# Why WebSocket Server is not loading

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, server-side

I have two files named test.html and server.py and I am trying to make a WebSocket server. 
Hence test.html is a client-side and server.py is server-side.
But Websocket server is not loading, please find below code :

test.html

```
<p id="status">Connecting...</p>
<input id="message" />
<button id="submit">Send</button>
<script>
  var socket = new WebSocket('wss://starlite3.tk/IncreedibleTanksServer');
  socket.onopen = function() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Connected";
  }
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    socket.send(document.getElementById("message").value);
  });
  socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
  }
  socket.onerrror = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "ERROR: "+e.target.CONNECTING
  }
</script>
```

server.py

```
import websockets
def start(websocket, uri):
    websocket.send('HI')
websockets.server.serve(start, "starlite3.tk", 0);
```

Comment: Try `ws://`, `wss://` is for secure web sockets

Comment: I tried it and it made the connection close. Do I have a problem with the code?